# ActiveMq not creating queue automaticlly

Tags: java, jms, activemq-classic

I create a destination like this:

```
 Destination destination = session.createQueue("queue_name");
```

In this case if the queue named "queue_name" dont exist, it will be created.

I want to form a destination to a queue and in case it dont exist, **i dont want to create it**.

Is there a way to connent to a queue only if it exists?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should be able to get a list of the available queues using DestinationSource from your connection. The you could look to see if the queue exists.

Havnt tried it, but think it looks like this:

```
        ActiveMQConnectionFactory connectionFactory = new ActiveMQConnectionFactory("tcp://localhost:61616");
        ActiveMQConnection connection = (ActiveMQConnection)connectionFactory.createConnection();
        DestinationSource ds = connection.getDestinationSource();
        Set<ActiveMQQueue> queues = ds.getQueues();
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to use the security feature in ActiveMQ to limit the users who are allowed to create destinations.  You can then configure a set of destinations in the ActiveMQ config which are always created.  See this [page](http://activemq.apache.org/how-do-i-create-new-destinations.html) on the subject and also this [page](http://activemq.apache.org/security.html) on configuring security.

Answer (score 0):

You can either do it through security configuration of your client (Consumer/Producer).

Or alternatively you can do it programmatically by getting the list of queues available and only connecting if it is in the list. ActiveMQ provides a class for this, but its not part of JMS (so you'll be restricted to an ActiveMQ specific implementation).

http://activemq.apache.org/maven/5.5.0/activemq-core/apidocs/org/apache/activemq/advisory/DestinationSource.html